# Microsoft .NET DLL in PublicAssemblies folder being deployed during build

Tags: c#, msbuild

We have a pretty large solution with several projects where a few reference the library, Microsoft.bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll, 6.0.0.0, Public Key Token cc7b13ffcd2ddd51. Scanning the output file during the build, I see that the reference to 6.0.0.0 DLL is being copied out to the build folder, but toward the end, the 5.0.0.0 DLL is being copied to the build folder.
The source of this copy is in VS is below

Copying file from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll" to ...

The VS file is version 5.0.0.0. I don't get it. There is literally nothing referencing this 5.0.0.0 DLL in VS and I don't know how it got there. If I delete this DLL, the build does what I think it should do, but my VS breaks.

Could this DLL be coming from an extension, and if so, why is it being used in my build?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/634312/msbuild-copies-dlls-from-its-currentbin-folder-and.html

Answer (score 0):

Setting the msbuild logging to "diag" was the key. Found out that the DLL in question was required by another library/DLL and that was forcing the usage of 5.0.0.0, even though the projects were trying to use 6.0.0.0. Changed all of the 6.0.0.0 references to 5.0.0.0 and all is good.